# java method that return an array of a classes

Tags: java, jsp

Im new to java an oop programming and I'm having trouble figuring out how to process this method in a .jsp file. Sorry about the limited info so Im going to elaborate cause I'm still stuck. I have a LoginServlet that gets input from a html file.

LoginServlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    loginInfo.setUsername(username);
    loginInfo.setPassword(password);

    request.setAttribute("login", loginInfo);
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = context.getRequestDispatcher("/Accounts.jsp");
    dispatch.forward(request, response);
}
```

Then I have JavaBean.java with accessors/mutators for password and username and the JavaBean also has this method

JavaBean - get/set methods for password & username and this method getAccounts()

```
public Account[] getAccounts() {
    return new Account[] {
            new Account(3001, "Checking", 29.96f , 2912.96f),
            new Account(4001, "Savings", 500.00f, 10030.50f),
            new Account(6001, "IRA", 1000.25f, 43456.83f)
            };

}
```

Ok, now finally I have the Account.java that only the JavaBean.java has access to so I need to create an instance using `getAccounts()` then access the getter and setters within Account.java. Last I'm going to include the Accounts.jsp code

Accounts.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="login" class="edu.pcc.cis234j.assign04b.LoginBean" scope="request">
 <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="login"/>  
</jsp:useBean> 
<h1>Welcome, <jsp:getProperty property="userName" name="login"/> How's your day going?</h1>
<% Account[] a = login.getAccounts(); %>
```

So how would I process this so I can display the new account info. without having access to Account.java and having this method within JavaBean.java returning an array of Account.java instances.

Comment: where is the `hard-coded` array?  What compiler error did you get?

Comment: more info please. Like if you have imported the class to the JSP, what error you see, if possible a SSCCE.

Comment: In jsp page you will have to add `reference / import Account[] class file` to access it's data and further processing.

Comment: @Nishant I have made the question complete now, sorry about that limited question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have this:

```
package p1;
public class Account{
  public Account(int x, String y, float f, float z){....}
}

package p2;
import p1;
public class Login{
 public Account[] getAccounts() {
  return new Account[] {
        new Account(3001, "Checking", 29.96f , 2912.96f),
        new Account(4001, "Savings", 500.00f, 10030.50f),
        new Account(6001, "IRA", 1000.25f, 43456.83f)
       };          
  } 
}
```

Then using scriplets you can access your jsp like this:

```
<%@page import="p1"%>
<%@page import="p2"%>
<%
  Login login = new Login();
  Account[] ac = login.getAccounts();
%>
```

PS: Make sure your imports are correct

Answer (score 1):

```
package test;

public class Account {

    String ac_id;
    String ac_bal;

    public Account(String ac_id, String ac_bal) {
        this.ac_id = ac_id;
        this.ac_bal = ac_bal;
    }

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account[] getAccounts() {
      return new Account[] {
            new Account("3001", "Checking"),
            new Account("4001", "Savings"),
            new Account("6001", "IRA")
          };          
    }
}
```

Above is java code ...

```
<%
        Account a = new Account();
        Account[] arr = a.getAccounts();
%>
```

This is jsp code.

It works fine without error.

Hopes this works.

Comment: @MavRoSCy Hey thanks for your help, I completed the question more and tried your example but Account cannot be resolved to a type, I have to access it through the JavaBean.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what was missing and I did to complete this.
First I imported the class make the compiler happy about the type Account.

```
<%@ page import="edu.pcc.cis234j.assign04b.LoginBean" %>
<%@ page import="edu.pcc.cis234j.assign04b.Account" %>
```

Then I was able to access the Account methods this way:

```
<% Account[] a = login.getAccounts(); %>


<% for(Account ac : a) { %>  
    <%= ac.getBalance() %>  
    <%= ac.getLastDeposit() %>
    <%= ac.getName() %>
    <%= ac.getId() %>
 <% } %>
```

Now I just need to format these result into a table or something, thanks for your guys help though. I usually fix my own problems with the push of asking questions. It just seems to get my mind rolling for some reason.